# Angular service injection hierarchy

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I have a service `MyService` which needs to be *defined* in a module `ModuleCommon`, and used in modules `ModuleA` and `ModuleB`. The dependencies of `MyService` vary between `ModuleA` and `ModuleB`.

Example:

```js
export class MyService {
  constructor(@Inject(XInjectionToken) dep: IDependency) { }
}
```

In `ModuleA`, `IDependency` implementation should be a `ModuleADependency`, whereas in `ModuleB` it's a `ModuleBDependency`.

How can I add `MyService` definition to `ModuleCommon` and 'defer' the injection of `XInjectionToken` until it can be provided by the child module?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add `MyService` to the providers array of `ModuleCommon` directly, without using the `{ provide: InjectionToken, useClass: MyService }` syntax. That appears to register the service with DI without instantiating it.